# Why does LoadableDetachableModel.detach sets transientModelObject = null?

Tags: wicket

In `LoadableDetachableModel` is `transientModelObject` a transient field. Why does the detach method sets

```
transientModelObject=null
```

I am asking this because it will not be serialized.

Comment: For a definitive answer you have to ask the author of that class, but my guess is to make whatever was referenced by it available for GC. (Or to be more precise: to avoid the LDM being the only thing holding GC back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the Page instance is kept in the http session as a live (non-serialized) object. The contract of `LoadableDetachableModel` says that its `modelObject` will be available during the request cycle. If it is not `null`-ified explicitly at `detach()` then it will be still available in the next request.

Comment: In `LoadableDetachableModel.getObject` always will be done: `transientModelObject = load()`, because `state==DETACHED` ( or the first time, `state==null`). So the model object will always be overwritten. So what do you mean when you say that it will still be available in the next request?

Comment: The states have been introduced few months ago. LDM is existing since 10 years. By `null`-ifying the model object manually we keep the Session size smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your components will stay in memory (if the container doesn't serialize the session to disk), so nullifying the reference minimzes memory consumption.

Why waster a lot of memory when you don't need it until the next request?